# Laravel : use parameter that taken from url for dynamic table name

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-routing

In controller, I want to use dynamic table name that taken from url and then show data using package chumper/datatable.

When I browse **mysite.com/unit/rentin/send** I have an AJAX error because the used table name is **send_{unit}** whereas my registered table name is **send_rentin**.

Here is my code:

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('unit.send', 'SendController');
```

**SendController.php**

```
class SendController extends \BaseController {    
    public function index($unit)
    {
        $table = new Send;     // Send is my model
        $table->setTable('send_' .$unit);

        if (Datatable::shouldHandle())
        {
            return Datatable::collection($table::all())
            ->showColumns('admin_no')
            ->addColumn('admin_date', function ($model) {
                return date('d M Y', strtotime($model->admin_date));
            })
            ->make();
        }

        return View::make('send.index')->withUnit($unit);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: I think `Route::resource('unit.send/{unit}', 'SendController');`

Comment: Actually `resource('unit.send', ...)` consist of one `get(unit/{unit}/send, ...)`. And this route that i use. `unit/rentin/send` similar to `unit/{unit}/send`.

Comment: The _$unit_ in last row `View::make('send.index')->withUnit($unit);` return _rentin_

Comment: That URI you are hitting doesn't match what routes the Resource creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hour try, I found a mistake at my **views**.

**Wrong**

```
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('no', 'date')
->setUrl(route('unit.send.index'))
->render('datatable.uikit') }}
```

**Right**

```
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('no', 'date')
->setUrl(route('unit.send.index', ['unit'=>$unit]))
->render('datatable.uikit') }}
```